# add a printer using only its Name

Tags: printing, addition

I would like to add a multifunction device type
printer/scanner
using powershell
I have one
code but no
works by name
or I have to add it several times

1-version  rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n "Brother DCP-J105 [40490f96a14b]"

2 -version
RUNDLL32.EXE PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /il  /n "NPI6B5E74 (HP LaserJet M15w)" F

3 version ( install printer all)
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,SHHelpShortcuts_RunDLL AddPrinter

Show what you’ve tried, tell us what happened, and why it didn’t meet your needs.

Not all questions benefit from including code, but if your problem is better understood with code you’ve written, you should include a minimal, reproducible example.

Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and not as images), and format them appropriately

I would like to add a multifunction device type
printer/scanner
using powershell
I have one
code but no
works by name
or I have to add it several times

1-version  rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n "Brother DCP-J105 [40490f96a14b]"

2 -version
RUNDLL32.EXE PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /il  /n "NPI6B5E74 (HP LaserJet M15w)" F

3 version ( install printer all)
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,SHHelpShortcuts_RunDLL AddPrinter